# Realtime: Node.js, MongoDB and Redis?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, socket.io

Okay, first of all I want to tell you that I am new to all this techniques mentioned in the title.

I want to make an new app. Think of it as a real time trading engine (like for stocks for example).

So, there are two things that really matter:

1. Speed / Performance: Everyone has to see trades in realtime
2. Security: Same trades can be made simultaneously but only one can be successful

I thought about an approach like this:

If a user wants to buy 10 peaces of stock X for $100 each he places an order which I store with Redis (speed) and push it to all clients with socket.io. Well, as soon as another user wants to sell 15 peaces for $100 the script should check if there is an open buy order. If so, it saves it as a successfull  transaction in **MongoDB** (persistance) and closes the buy order of 10 peaces.

In this example 5 peaces are left. The script would display that with a calculation like this: 15 (sell at $100) minus 10 (buy at $100) equals 5 left. Every time someone want's to trade something this calculation would be made because I don't know how many stocks are left for trading else.

Edit: Or I could subtract 10 peaces of the 15 peaces in Redis so that I don't need to calculate every time. But if something would go wrong, I wouldn't know what the original data was. That's a problem.

**Now the questions are:**

1. Would you make it like this? Better ideas maybe?
2. What would happen if two users make the exact same order in the same time? Could it happen, that it gets stored two times in MongoDB as different successfull transactions? Of course you could run an audit over Redis and MongoDB and compare it. But that would be a horrible solution.

Hope you understand what I'm trying to ask. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should make it as transaction

Comment: You mean like begin transaction, write it to mongo and within this transaction change the data in redis? Are transactions truly consecutively?

Answer (score 2):

First of all if you do not know anything from the stack you are using, it is not a good idea to tell I need high performance (high availability, good security and so on). Being absolutely new to all the tools you are using you should be happy if it will just work.

As for your question: first of all take a look how other people have done similar things. [Here is an open source bitcoin trading engine which uses node.js](https://github.com/buttercoin/buttercoin) which makes it an excellent example to study (it is complex, so take a deep breath). If you want to use mongo you need to know that it does not support transactions, so you need to take a look how to implement them by yourself there. [These two](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/) examples are really good in [explaining it](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/perform-two-phase-commits/).

Comment: Thank you! The open source project surely helps a lot. Of course it's a problem if you're new to it. So I thought about learning by doing and making it better and better step by step. But for that to start I needed the right direction. It would be dumb to create it only to detect later that it was a completely wrong way.